# Is there way to connect to Gradle daemon launched by Gradle Tooling APIs from command line

Tags: eclipse, gradle, daemon, enide, gradle-daemon

When IDE compiles gradle project there is java process in memory ( about 250MB).

However launching `gradle buld --daemon` other daemon java process is launched (about 150MB)

[image: 2 gradle daemon processes]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SUBd.png

Is there way to connect to Gradle daemon launched by Gradle Tooling APIs from command line.

More info from http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle

> #### Design differences
>
> Pivotal Gradle IDE uses [Gradle Tooling API, see Chapter 62 of User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/embedding.html).
>   This is recommended integration by GradleWare.
>   In contrast Enide Gradle launches `gradle` executable similar how you do from command line. (And similar to [Enide Maven](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/maven))
>   The API is simpler, just as what you see from `gradle -h`, but of course it will not give access to underlying model as with Tooling API.
>
> Since 0.15 `--daemon` option is enabled by default [see Chapter 19. The Gradle Daemon](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html).
>   And as Tooling API also uses Gradle Deamon, the performance is similar: i.e. a bit longer first run, second run is faster and optimized.
>   Read also about [incremental builds](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/faster_incremental_builds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to reuse the same Gradle daemon process when requesting build from IDE and/or command line. If you see new process created then it is most likely because one of the situations described in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#reusing_daemons happened. You can try to look into daemon log files to see how they were invoked (Java home, args, distribution, ...) and to see why it is not reused. In your image it looks that one daemon uses Gradle 1.10 and the 2nd 1.10.

Comment: Brilliant. When the same version is configured in Pivotal Gradle IDE, Enide Gradle or on system PATH, then daemon is reused. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-ide-pack